# Tyre popped when going from 26 x 1.95 to 26 x 2.125

Tags: tire, innertube, bike-fit, sealant

My wheel had 26 x 1.95 tyres. I bought 26 x 2.125 thinking it would fit.

While fitting the new tyre, it bulged outside at one location and the tube also came out for about 7 inches. The tube is the one with slime sealant inside so I am not able to take the air out of tube. I ordered the valve core tool to remove the valve. The tube is also relatively new, I bought it about couple of months back.

My questions are

1. can I reuse the tube after the removing the valve and deflate the tube ?
2. can the tyre be used or it is not fitting, that is why it bulged in one place ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your predicament. If a tire has been properly mounted and the tire is bulging, it needs to be thrown out.

Comment: I "think" I did not put the tire well. It is a new tire. I just bought it.

Comment: Sounds like to me that it isn't seated right.  Happens to all of us from time to time.  You'll find your answer below.

Comment: Valve core tool? The tube is toast due to slime: air doesn't move; cut the valve off.

Answer (score 4):

I would say, you just didn't put the tire on well. When you inflate the tire to half its recommended pressure you should check that the tire seats well for the whole diameter around the rim on both sides. If it came out even a little, push it back in (may require some deflating). Otherwise the pressure may push the tire out like you had, and then the tube can explode.

For your questions: both the tire and the tube can be used again. But check accurately that the tire's bead is not damaged.

Comment: I fixed it! Thanks for the help. I removed the valve and deflated the tube. Place the tire properly. Only problem i had was the valve is filled with the sealant, so I took once the old tube and replaced it. Now all good

Comment: Next time deflate a sealant tube when the valve is up, and all the sealant is at it's bottom.

Comment: Thanks. how to find out the sealant at the bottom? is that not normal that sealant is near the valve when pumped up?

Comment: If I understand you right, you had a glue inside the tube that seal punctures. Now this glue (like any liquid) is always flowing down. Therefor, when you deflate the tube, if the valve is at the bottom point of the tube, the sealant will flow to the valve and try to exit with the air through the valve. If you put your wheel with the valve at upper side, the sealant will flow down, and will not disturb you while you deflate the tube.